# visual basic 6 offline api documentation

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

Does anyone have an offline visual basic 6 api documentation in pdf, chm or hlp format.
Any help is welcome, nothing is too OLD documentation..

PS: I don't know where else to post it. Please move the post to correct section if it is in incorrect section

Comment: What do you mean by "visual basic 6 api documentation"?  VB6 comes with offline documentation (or mine did anyway).

Comment: yes, can you provide a link

Comment: The documentation is all online [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh127509.aspx), totally free. Just get one of those automatic web downloader thingadongdongs that can follow x levels of nested links, and rip it off of the site.

Comment: I don't feel this is off topic, it's not asking to recommend a tool or library or book; it's a very specific question for how to get the off-line documentation (a specific thing) a couple of years after it was released.

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN library for VB6 ships with the installer discs and [can be downloaded from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/#FileId=4053). The MSDN installation is available offline after installation to your machine.

I don't think there is an official download for non-subscribers. So you either need to find the discs that shipped with the original product, or download them from your subscription.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is that I saved the content, API description from the website in docx. Yes it took time. about 20 mins